# Accessing individual column using database link

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, database-link

I am new to Oracle world. I have recently created a Database Link in Oracle to fetch the data from SQL Server and I am able to fetch the data.

```
SELECT * FROM emp@dblink
```

The above query fetching all the rows from "emp" table hosted on SQL Server.

But when I refer a specific column as shown below, Oracle throwing an error.

```
--This query failed
SELECT empid FROM emp@dblink
```

**Error:** ORA-00904: "EMPID": invalid identifier

But when I enclose the empid column in double quotes, it started working.

```
--This query passed
SELECT "empid" FROM emp@dblink
```

I am wondering why did I get an error when I refer the individual column without enclosing it in double quotes.

Comment: maybe case sensitive issue , check from emp that empid is capital or small letter, as for the double quotes it specific the case sensitivity

Comment: It is small in emp table. However, I tried with both small & capital with no luck. I suspect this could be due to some configuration issue of SQL Server driver but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**[TL;DR] The simplest thing to do is to never use double quotes around object names and just let oracle manage the case-sensitivity in its default manner and if you are referencing columns in a case-sensitive database over a dblink then name those columns in upper-case so you do not have to use double-quotes in Oracle.**

Oracle databases are, by default, case sensitive; however, they will also, by default, convert everything to upper-case so that the case sensitivity is abstracted from you, the user.

```
CREATE TABLE emp ( empid NUMBER(12,0) );
```

Then:

```
SELECT empid FROM emp;
SELECT Empid FROM emp;
SELECT EMPID FROM emp;
SELECT eMpId FROM emp;
SELECT "EMPID" FROM emp;
```

Will all give the same output and:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS;
```

Outputs:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME
---------- -----------
EMP        EMPID
```

(Note the table name is in upper case).

If you use double quotes then oracle will respect your use of case in object identifiers:

```
CREATE TABLE emp ( "empid" NUMBER(12,0) );
```

Then:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS;
```

Outputs:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME
---------- -----------
EMP        empid
```

(Note: Oracle has respected the case sensitivity of the `empid` column).

and you can now only reference the column using:

```
SELECT "empid" FROM emp;
```

and these queries will fail:

```
SELECT empid FROM emp;
SELECT Empid FROM emp;
SELECT EMPID FROM emp;
SELECT eMpId FROM emp;
SELECT "EMPID" FROM emp;
```

As Oracle will convert the identifier to upper-case and there is no `EMPID` column, only an `empid` column.

Either use double-quotes to reference the column or rename the column to `EMPID` to allow you to utilise Oracle's default behaviour of abstracting the case-sensitivity from the user (but this might break other queries which do use double-quotes on the non-upper-case column name).

Comment: Hi, the Emp table is hosted on SQL Server but not in Oracle and I am trying to access it using DBLinks. The column name in SQL Server is exactly the way I have mentioned in my query, i.e., empid.

Comment: @SumanKumar Same thing applies - Oracle is case-sensitive but its default behaviour is to convert all identifiers to upper-case. So when you do `SELECT empid FROM emp@dblink` Oracle will parse it to `SELECT EMPID FROM emp@dblink` and the query will fail when it reaches SQL Server, which is also case-sensitive and has the column as a different case. Either use double-quotes to tell Oracle to respect the case-sensitivity of the name and not to convert the identifier to upper-case or rename the column in SQL Server to be `EMPID` (upper-case) and you should be able to use unquoted identifiers.

Comment: SQL Server is by default case-insensitive,i.e, whether it is empid, EmpID or EMPID all are same for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, columns in the data dictionary are typically case-insensitive in that:

```
select empno from EMP
select EMPNO from emp
select EMPNO from Emp
```

will all happily match against a column called EMPNO in the data dictionary for the called EMP. If you want to have case-sensitivity then you use double quotes, eg

```
select "EmpNo" from EMP
```

would work as long as the EMP table was originally defined with:

```
create table emp ("EmpNo" int)
```

etc. SQL Server is different and preserves the case in the dictionary, so when we query it from Oracle across a dblink we are preserving the case. So a column called MixedCase in SQL Server must be referenced as "MixedCase" from Oracle.

Comment: Hi, the Emp table is hosted on SQL Server and the column is exactly the way I have mentioned, i.e., empid

Comment: Oracle is case-sensitive - it is just the default behaviour is to convert unquoted identifiers to upper-case which masks the case sensitivity from the user.

Comment: @SumanKumar And exactly as I have mentioned: 'So a column called MixedCase in SQL Server must be referenced as "MixedCase" from Oracle.'

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald - Is there is any way to turn this off (so that I can refer MixedCase in SQL Server as MixedCase in DB link)? Maybe through some collation settings in Oracle Gateway configuration?

Comment: create views in Oracle (or SQL Server) along thelines of:

create view UPPER_CASE_NAME as select * from "sql_server_mixed_case_name";

and then refer to UPPER_CASE_NAME